# cross-posting etiquette

Tags: discussion

Many of my questions, and most of my answers, involve SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS).  I don't believe we have a good concentration of experts on this tool here (yet) and I have seen some SSRS-related questions get good attention and feedback on Stack Overflow.

I try to be supportive of dba.se and flag some questions over there for migration and such, but the fact seems to be SSRS folks are not paying attention to dba.se.

I have a sticky question that I need to figure out ([rsExecutionNotFound when directly accessing an SSRS report](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/21974/3928)) and it has gotten minimum attention here, likely due to lack of expertise.  What's the etiquette regarding posting the same question at SO, where I think it will get more attention and, hopefully, a response?

I want to be a supporter of dba.se and a good community member of SE sites in general!  :)

Comment: I would say to ask the moderators about whether the question should be migrated or not. If not, perhaps ask the user to also "copy" their question here and link them. If it is answered here, then you can always post a "linked" answer on SO. I've done that with a few questions and I think it helps bring visibility to dba.se on SO.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you flag the question and ask it to be migrated to Stack Overflow, rather than crossposting it yourself.

Comment: My question is more that I feel this question would be answered at Stack Overflow because the SSRS experts haven't come over here yet... so I want to crosspost it in order to solve my problem... and maybe promote dba.se at the same time?

Comment: Eh, maybe comment on it once migrated "well, it didn't get any love on [dba], why not you guys?"

Comment: @JHFB - provided the mods don't delete the question here after migration, there's still a stub here that points to the migrated post on SO. SO you get a kind of hybrid cross-post.

Comment: We rarely intervene to delete the stub, it would have to be egregious. The system, however, deletes stubs about a month after migration.